$\sigma$-algebra generated by conditional expectation
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. I would like to prove (or disprove)
$$\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right) \supseteq \sigma \left( X \right)$$
By definition of conditional expectation I know $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right]$ is $\sigma \left( X \right)$-measurable. And $\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right]$ measurable. In particular, this implies
$$\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right) \subseteq \sigma \left( X \right)$$
but does inclusion in the other direction hold as well?

If $Y$ is independent of $X$, then $\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right) = \sigma (\mathbb E[Y])$ is the trivial sigma algebra. Therefore no, the other inclusion does not hold in general.
